# How to keep results filtered by selectbox even after page refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, session-cookies

I'am using the *CodeIgniter*. I have a global category list, which is separated into the several **components** such as (Conten articles, E-commerce, Users, Banners, etc...). There is `/categories/get_categories` page where I display all rows from Database Table `ci_categories`.

On that page, there is a `<select>` box with the `<options>` of available `ci_categories.com_id` (components). Whenever I select one of them, either *Users* or *E-commerce* it will send the POST data `/categories/get_categories/$com_id` and it will filter the category items corresponding to the component's id `com_id`.  All of this works great.

But what I want is to keep this filter selected and do not return to default selection (all components). For example, I click on Categories - it will output all category rows in a `<table>`. There I choose an option from a dropdown selectbox list, and it will filter the specific rows output, then i Click **Add new category**, and it should pass that selected component option to the next page. On the next FORM page, where I add a new item informations, i Click on SAVE, and it should return me to the previous page where All of categories are listed, but with that filter `com_id` selected.

Any suggestion ? Is there a way to do it without sessions or cookies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to make use of sessions as they are especially meant to store data between requests based on the current user experience. Most people only search the website in one browser window, so it shouldn't give a real problem. Even if there are other options, you always need to identify the user by a specific code which will be stored in session/cookie.

The only option I can think of is changing every link afterwards to contain the stored information in a base64 encoded string. But that would ruin your link structure and needs canonical links on every page to show the right url to search engines.

I would suggest you to stick to Sessions, as they are handled fine in CodeIgniter. You can even store them in the database if you want by setting that in the main config file.

Flashdata is an option, but it's a session in the end anyway but only lives one request.

Comment: thanks, but pls could you tell me why it's not better to use cookies ? as i need to store filters and in CI docs is said that in Session I can store max 4kb

Comment: Cookies can be used if they also need to persist between visits, and not only in that session. Keep in mind indeed that cookies have a maximum size, but that should be no big problem to you. I wouldn't rely totally on cookies as they could get edited by the end user, but if it's non-sensible information you should be fine. You asked for a solution without sessions/cookies but I think you need them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can use session flashdata like this:

Set  flashdata

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('search','your_search');
```

Read flashdata

```
$this->session->flashdata('search');
```

flashdata is setted for only one refresh, after the refresh the variable is deleted

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: What if I will move to another page, do the necessary stuff there, and want to return on the category page with filtered items as before leaving that page ? Should i store user's config in cookies or in sessions ?

Comment: In this mode you can store your filter in many session vars, and when you return to your search page you can check if this session exist or not.